# How to recover Fabric Account from App ID

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

Unfortunately, everyone in  this team is new to this legacy project and no one knows credential for the fabric account login, if I know the app id how can I recover the login

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sam! This is only possible through Fabric support on a case by case basis. They will require some security steps to make sure you control the app.

Do you have control of the web domain that the registered emails were at? Email the bundle ID or package name to support@fabric.io and we'll work with you to see what we can do.

Todd - Fabric team

Comment: I just emailed you the app id to "support@fabric.io"